# Is there a Minimum number of datasets for comparing classifiers with Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test?

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank

I am interested in comparing Classifier A with Classifier B. I have accuracy of five datasets for each classifier. I want to apply non-parametric test like wilcoxon signed rank test because I want to find out if Classifier A is better than B.  Is correct to apply this test using five datasets? because in some tables of Wilcoxon do not have a value (have "--") for n=5 and other tables have zero value.

The data are:

```
dataset A   B
a   58.47   66.52
b   60.69   73.54
c   60.95   84.85
d   55.39   58.77
e   80.01   77.43
```

In R with scmamp a statistical significance can be observed.

Comment: It is not obvious to me that this is a valid thing to do. Can you provide a bit more detail about the data? E.g., perhaps show the data?